# How or where I could experience sonoluminescence in daily life?

Tags: visible-light, acoustics

Sonoluminescence is a known phenomenon, even if a conclusive explanation for its origin is not given. I wonder if I could ever hear and see sonoluminescence somehow or somewhere in daily life, or if it's a very rare event that only a lab can reproduce.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence

Comment: also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9B3vzsZsr4 ,  https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/370/1/012065/pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the effect only happens under very high energies, one would think that this

> or if it's a very rare event that only a lab can reproduce

is the most likely alternative. However, sonoluminescence has been observed at least in one case in nature:

Pistol shrimps can snap a specialized claw shut to create a cavitation bubble that generates acoustic pressures of up to 80 kPa at a distance of 4 cm from the claw, strong enough to kill small fish.

The snap can also produce sonoluminescence from the collapsing cavitation bubble. As it collapses, the cavitation bubble reaches temperatures of over 5,000 K *(the surface temperature of the sun is around 5,800 K)*, although the intensity is still too low to be seen by the naked eye.

Another group of crustaceans, the mantis shrimp, contains species whose club-like forelimbs can strike so quickly and with such force as to induce sonoluminescent cavitation bubbles upon impact. The intensity and the duration of the light are also, however, too weak and too short to be detected without equipment.

Comment: Does this phenomenon needs to be in some liquid to happen?